# Manipulating arrays within another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following:

```
const entries = 
[
   ["mango", 2],
   ["orange", 3],
   ["strawberry", 0],
   ["banana", 10]
]
```

I would like to iterate over the arrays inside entries[], remove any arrays that have a 0 and have them going in descending order, so the above would change to:

```
newArr = 
[
   ["banana", 10]
   ["orange", 3]
   ["mango", 2]
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let entries = 
[
   ["mango", 2],
   ["orange", 3],
   ["strawberry", 0],
   ["banana", 10]
]

entries = entries.filter(pr => pr[1] !== 0);
entries.sort((pr, nt) => nt[1] - pr[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done through `filter` and `sort`:

```
const result = entries.filter(f => f[1] != 0).sort((a, b)=> b[1] - a[1]);
```

An example:

```js
let entries =
[
   ["mango", 2],
   ["orange", 3],
   ["strawberry", 0],
   ["banana", 10]
];


const result = entries.filter(f => f[1] != 0).sort((a, b)=> b[1] - a[1]);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const entries = [["mango", 2], ["orange", 3], ["strawberry", 0], ["banana", 10]]

function filterSort (arr) {
  return entries
    .filter(([, num]) => num > 0)
    .sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)
}

console.log(filterSort(entries))
```

Note that the `entries` array is not modified. No items were removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and `sort` methods with destructure.

```js
const entries = [
  ["mango", 2],
  ["orange", 3],
  ["strawberry", 0],
  ["banana", 10]
];

const result = entries.filter(([,x]) => x).sort(([,a], [,b]) => b - a);

console.log(result);
```